# Access VBA help filtering

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a main form with a search box, the search filters the supervisor into a subform called `subfrmSupRes`, when the id is clicked.

I'd like it to filter the users results into another subform called `subfrmUsrRes`, I get a 438 run time error 'object doesn't support this property or method'.

When I debug the code, the variable I need is seen in the `strWhere` variable. Could someone give some advice?

```
Private Sub Sup_ID_Click()
Dim strWhere As String
    With Forms!frmSupResults!subfrmSupRes!Sup_ID
        If .Text = vbNullString Then
            strWhere = "(false)"
        Else
            strWhere = "frmsupresults.subfrmSupRes.Sup_ID like """ & .Text      & "*"""
        End If
    End With
    With Forms!frmSupResults!subfrmUsrRes!Sup_ID
        .Filter = strWhere
        .FilterOn = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here are all of the changes from the comments, all in one code block:

```
Private Sub Sup_ID_Click()
    Dim strWhere As String
    With Forms.frmSupResults.subfrmSupRes!Sup_ID
        If .Text = vbNullString Then
            strWhere = ""
        Else
            strWhere = "[Sup_ID] like """ & .Text & "*"""
        End If
    End With
    With Forms.frmSupResults.subfrmUsrRes.Form
        If Len(strWhere) > 0 Then
            .Filter = strWhere
            .FilterOn = True
        Else
            .FilterOn = False
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Summary of fixes:

1. Fix 'blanking out' on no ID value: `strWhere = ""`
2. Let Sup_ID refer to field in subfrmUsrRes form query or SQL: `strWhere = "[Sup_ID] like """ & .Text & "*"""`
3. Refer to .Form property of subform: `With Forms.frmSupResults.subfrmUsrRes.Form`
4. Check for filter before applying: `If Len(strWhere) > 0 Then`
5. Turn filter off if no filter: `.FilterOn = False`

This should get you pretty close. The only thing that I cannot answer for you is whether `Sup_ID` is a valid field in the query or SQL for `subfrmUsrRes.Form`.

Comment: now I'm having another issue, here is the revised code, the error is 438 object doesn't support this property or method. [Private Sub Sup_ID_Click()
Dim strWhere As String
        With Forms.frmSupResults.subfrmUsrRes.[Sup_ID]
        If .Text = vbNullString Then
            strWhere = "(false)"
        Else
            strWhere = "[Sup_ID] like """ & .Text & "*"""
        End If
        End With
        With Forms.frmSupResults.subfrmUsrRes
        .Filter = strWhere
        .FilterOn = True
        
        End With
End Sub
]

Comment: You may need to explicitly refer to the form under the subform control.
Try:
`With Forms.frmSupResults.subfrmUsrRes.Form.Sup_ID`
And:
`With Forms.frmSupResults.subfrmUsrRes.Form`

Comment: 1) Open the form referred to by `subfrmSupRes` by itself. 2) Paste one of your generated `strWhere` values directly into the forms Filter property. 3) Open the form. Does it restrict to the specified Sup_ID? Does it throw an error? Let me know.

Comment: 1. The `strWhere = "(false)"` is responsible for the 'blanking out'. Since False will never be True, this will show no records.
2. Try putting the `strWhere` filter string for a *known* Sup_ID directly in the RecordSource as a real WHERE clause for the form referred to by `subfrmSupRes`. Does that work?

Comment: been struggling with this today, tried this    Private Sub Sup_ID_Click()
Dim strWhere As Variant
    varWhere = Me.Sup_ID
    With Forms.frmsupresults.subfrmUsrRes.Form
        .Filter = strWhere
        .FilterOn = True
    End With
End Sub

Comment: Your line `varWhere = Me.Sup_ID ` has to be changed to something like `strWhere = "[Sup_ID] = '" & Me.Sup_ID & "'"`  (I put in single quotes for readability)

Comment: Edited to include ! in the line you noted (subfrmSupRes!Sup_ID)

Answer (score -2):

I needed to add the explanation before the subform control.

```
Private Sub Sup_ID_Click()
Dim strWhere As String
With Forms.frmSupResults.subfrmSupRes!Sup_ID
    If .Text = vbNullString Then
        strWhere = ""
    Else
        strWhere = "[Sup_ID] like """ & .Text & "*"""
    End If
End With
With Forms.frmSupResults.subfrmUsrRes.Form
    If Len(strWhere) > 0 Then
        .Filter = strWhere
        .FilterOn = True
    Else
        .FilterOn = False
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: So, how is your answer any different from mine? Why take credit for your own answer when I did the work to get you there?

Comment: You absolutely did the work and I appreciate it, the only thing was it didn't work without the exclamation as it wasn't a system control! In my mind, you did all the work, not really sure how I'm taking credit, but if so I do so apologize and appreciate your efforts!